# Why are comparative adjectives used here, with the definite article? "...a hatred, the deeper for being concealed..."

Tags: adjectives, comparatives

In this sentence, the article 'the' precedes several comparative adjectives: 'deeper', 'bitter', 'greater', and 'stronger'. Now, for context, this sentence is the beginning of a text, and the adjectives are not compared with anything.

> Terry soon became jealous of Sabina, and this rivalry turned at last to a hatred, the deeper for being concealed, and the more bitter in that he knew she had the greater power and the stronger will.

My question is: Why are the comparative forms of the adjective used when there is no comparison (and no, there is no 'implied' comparison to my knowledge), and why does the definite article precede them? I am aware that there are similar constructions to this (I believe they are called 'comparative correlatives'):

> The sooner, the better.
>
> The more one eats, the larger one will get.
>
> The faster we run, the sooner we will get there.

However, in most of these, there is a comparison. Here, there are not any comparisons (and, before someone in the comments yells 'Context! Context!', there is **no** implied comparison available from the context). Is this a special use of the comparative adjective?

Comment: The implied comparison is with the unconcealed version.

Comment: English demonstratives are *this, these, that, those* — **ɴᴏᴛ** *the below*.  I don't know what part of the world keeps tricking learners into those belows of theirs but it isn't natural English.  Other possibilities include *the following, the enclosed, the highlighted* &c &c &c &c &c.

Answer (score 8):

The [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/200212?rskey=TBougW&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid) has an entry for this use of *the*:

> a. Used with a following comparative adjective or adverb to emphasize
> the effect of circumstances indicated by the context.The circumstances
> are sometimes expressed by a phrase introduced by *for*, e.g. *he is
> much the better for it, he looks the better for his holiday*.
>
> 1724   Modest Def. Publick Stews 51   She will be the easier bribed,
> when Love and Avarice jointly must be gratified.
>
> 1782   W. Cowper Mutual Forbearance in Poems 24   Your fav'rite horse
> Will never look one hair the worse.
>
> 1838   J. Ruskin Ess. Music & Painting §24, in Wks. (1903) I. 285
> And if others do not follow their example,—the more fools they.
>
> 1883   Law Times 27 Oct. 425/1   What student is the better for
> mastering these futile distinctions?
>
> 1938   Manch. Guardian 8 Mar. 8/1   This record is the more remarkable
> when we remember the defective eyesight by which..Dr. Garvie has been
> handicapped.
>
> 2014   K. Fforde Christmas Feast 289   She wouldn't really be any the
> wiser.

There is also a discussion of this in the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language p1131-1132

> i *This didn’t make her achievement* [***any the less*** *significant*].
>
> ii *In the Swedish context, notable for its tradition of peace and
> non-violence, the senseless futility of this act stands out* [***the*
> *more*** *starkly*].
>
> iii *The plight of the four British employees greatly perturbed
> Urquhart*, [***the more***] *because a request to the Governor for a
> contingent of Cossacks to escort them to safety had been turned down*.
>
> iv *The result is* [***all the more*** *disappointing*] *because she had put
> in so much effort*.
>
> v *That’s*  [***all the more*** *reason to avoid precipitous action*].
>
> vi *He went prone on his stomach*, [***the better***] *to pursue his
> examination*.
>
> *The* here modifies the following comparative (*more, less, better*), forming a phrase which in turn is modifier to an adjective ([i/iv]),
> an adverb ([ii]), a verb ([iii/vi]) or determiner to a nominal ([v]).
> In [i-ii] *the* is freely omissible. In [iii] the underlined
> occurrence of *the* would be omissible if it introduced a modifier
> rather than a supplement (which would mean dropping the comma), but
> not as it stands. In [iv], *all the* might be glossed as “even”, or
> *all the*+ comparative as “especially”; *the* can only be omitted if *all* is omitted too. Example [v] is similar, except that *all the mor*e is here a DP functioning as determiner in NP structure. In [vi]
> *the better* is a fronted modifier in the infinitival clause of purpose; *the* is obligatory in this position but optional in the
> basic position - compare *in order to pursue his examination* (*the*)
> *better*.
>
> *The* is completely excluded if the secondary term is expressed: **The result was the better than I had expected*. Nor is *the* permitted
> when the secondary term is recoverable anaphorically, from what has
> gone before. We cannot, for example, insert *the* in *It was cloudy
> and cold for the first two days but on the third day the weather was
> better*, where we understand “better than on the first two days”.

Comment: Thank you very much, DW256.

Answer (score 3):

It's a literary usage, with as @Lawrence says an **implicit** comparison. Compare

- "How are you, Kerry?" ... "All the better for seeing you."

You can easily fill in the deletion / adjustment here:

- ... "All the better than would have been the case had I not seen you."

It's good to have the pithier, more punchy alternative.

So

- ' ... deeper than it would have been if it had not been concealed' /
- ' ... [even] more bitter than would have been the case had he not known she had the greater power and the stronger will'.

Comment: How is this a literary usage? "All the better for seeing you" seems normal spoken English (at least in UK); maybe a little old fashioned but nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: Certainly "How are you?" "Much the same." would be a completely natural and colloquial exchange.

Comment: But 'The better for seeing you' and 'The same' would follow the pattern here. and according to a raw Google search there are very few examples of the first. The second we'll have to agree is unidiomatic in this usage.  There are a few fixed phrases in common use, but the OP example is certainly in a literary style. DW256's examples from OED typically smack of a literary or even archaic flavour. 'She wouldn't really be any the wiser' of course employs another fixed phrase.